# How to open a list of links with window API and loading them lazily?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to build a mini scraper program and I don't want to overload the server of the website and get a 429 error.

I want to open a big chunk (hundreds) of links in new Chrome tabs, but "lazily".

I used this method:

```
linksArray.forEach((link) => {
   window.open(link, "_blank", "noopener")
}
```

Even if I specify the "noopener" each page is already loaded when I click on its tab.

I would like if possible to postpone loading of the page's contents until I focus the specific tab.

Thanks, a lot

Comment: Where is this code running? Is this a normal JS script inside of a webpage? If so, you really need something that uses chrome dev tools protocol like Pupeteer to do this task -- it would be impossible to do it from a website on a different domain as you wont be able to read the DOM of those popups anyway -- XSS protection and CORS protection will stop you.

Comment: Yes it's a simple <script>

Comment: Yeh so basically its wrong tool for the job. You wont be able to read the DOM from an external site in those popups anyway so scraping wont be possible -- browser security protections will stop you. For this, you'd need a serverside solution.

Comment: Ok, I will think about this scraping the problem, still haven't started writing server-side code. I want to solve the first problem first: I want Chrome to not load new tabs until selected. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Essentially that is also impossible unless you control the actual site being loaded -- the parent context cant control those windows. It is by design in browsers. What you could do though, to achieve the same effect, is push them through a throttled queue. This would mean it would launch the tabs over a period of time rather than in one go. However -- you will quickly find you cant do anything with those tabs anyway including getting data out of them. However if you still want the queue answer let me know.

Comment: Don't want to bother you, but still I'd like to hear your idea. Actually, I tried to create a delayed opening of the links with setInterval but the limits of this website before throwing a 429 err are too strict. It would become too slow of a process.

Comment: Right -- and thats their attempt at stopping you from doing this. No matter what method you use, you will always be at the mercy of the rate limiting. Even if this was serverside, there would be no different. And with the throttle method, it would have to be tuned so low as to not trigger 429. There is no way around that, no matter what you do, unless you are looking to create a botnet. At that point, depending on jurisdiction, it may also be illegal. Unfortunately, you may need to reconsider your task,

Comment: (delayed opening with setInterval is roughly equivalent to throttle, so you've basically already explored this. You cant circumvent it, since the restrictions are serverside).

Comment: Yes, I get it. I gave up and changing the scope of my program. Thanks

Comment: Probably makes sense! Try searching for alternative sources with an API available for whatever data it is that you need.